# LTE D2D Mode Selection in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, lte

I want to implement my own mode selection method in `OMNeT++ 5.0` using the `simulte-0.9.1` framework.

According to the demos and the paper from the authors, mode selection should generally be enabled liked this in the `.ini`:

```
*.eNodeB.nic.phy.enableD2DCqiReporting = true
*.eNodeB.nic.d2dModeSelection = true
*.eNodeB.nic.d2dModeSelectionType="D2DModeSelectionBestCqi"
```

The `BestCQI mode selection method` is already implemented and would serve as a nice example on how to implement new methods. Unfortunately OMNeT++ complains that all three are `unused parameters`. I simulated something for a short while and had a look at the logs. In `simulte/src/stack/d2dModeSelection/d2dModeSelectionBestCqi/D2DModeSelectionBestCqi.cc` the very first line in the `doModeSelection()` function it says

```
EV << NOW << " D2DModeSelectionBestCqi::doModeSelection - Running Mode Selection algorithm..." << endl;
```

but no such output comes up when I run the simulation, so it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that these parameters actually work, even though they're marked `unused`. I simulated two scenarios: one with `mode selection off` and one with `on` and had a look at different throughput scalars.

[Throughput with mode selection off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDvit.jpg)

[Throughput with mode selection on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGCQY.jpg)

The eNB sees a lot of traffic when these parameters are present. I don't see how the traffic could be as large as it is in my simulation, but at least it seems to have an effect.